# Is it fine to ask questions about Deep Web?

Tags: discussion

This is the only forum which could address so many questions that one might have about deep web. Are they are off topic?

Comment: What's the "Deep Web"?  Do I even want to know?

Comment: Tor enables users to access Deep Web, and from what I know it is the only channel which does so. There are things like why does the web addresses look so bad, which is the webpage with best index of websites, etc.

Comment: @weasel-PeterPalfrader: :-) By "Deep Web" we usually mean the web which is not being indexed by standard search engines like Google, Yahoo, ask.com, Bing etc. BTW Tor is not the only channel to access Deep Web (DW). Web servers running as Tor hidden services are just a part of DW. Another part of DW is accessible directly by a normal browser without additional tools, you just have to know the addresses.

Comment: Semantics aside, there are many resources that aren't available directly from the Internet. Generally, each requires some gateway. Such gateways include Tor, I2P and Freenet clients, for example. But there are also various peering arrangements with and among alternate address spaces, isolated (I gather) in various ways from the Internet. For example, one can imagine networks of hidden services. Are they (if they exist) part of Tor? They might be Freenets or Tahoe-LAFS grids. Semantics get complicated here.

Comment: Could you maybe give an example of what type of questions do you have in mind?

Comment: I have mentioned a few things in the first comment. How legitimate are the weapon selling websites, how silk route delivery system never gets caught, but I know by myself these will be off topic. How anonymous one is while surfing deep web is I think synonymous with anonymity while using Tor.

Comment: New, related meta discussion: http://meta.tor.stackexchange.com/questions/90/is-it-fine-to-ask-questions-about-deep-web

Answer (score 4):

**I think that it is OK if is related to Tor.** Tor gives access to Deep Internet, but not every questions about "that second network" are on-topic here. You can ask for example about "how to access deep web using tor", but questions about Deep Web in general should be closed. **That page is for Tor issues and issues to Tor related.**